# projections are not allowed for immediate subtypes of a supertype

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an abstract class like the following:

```
abstract class AbstractSync<out C : Configuration<*>> : ISync {
    internal abstract val configuration: C
    ...
}
```

I want another abstract class that inherits from this:

```
abstract class CascadedSync : AbstractSync {}
```

The CascadedSync class should not modify the generic parameter C, it should, in fact, only implement a single method of ISync and nothing else.

I am trying out different syntaxes to achive this seemingly simple task.
In Java, this would look just like this:

```
abstract class CascadedSync extends AbstractSync {    
}
```

Translating it to Kotlin with the help of IntelliJ produces this:

```
abstract class CascadedSync : AbstractSync<*>()
```

But at the same time gives the following error:

***projections are not allowed for immediate subtypes of a supertype***

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, type parameters are not implicitly copied from types to their subtypes and, even if you don't modify them, they should be redeclared in the subtype declaration:

```
abstract class CascadedSync<out C : Configuration<*>> : AbstractSync<C>() {
    // ...
}
```